# Heroku - Ruby error loop

Tags: ruby, heroku, papertrail-app

I have not made any changes to ruby files, just a few layout changes and am seeing the following errors in Papertrail on my server.  I did some digging by can't seem to find an answer.

Also the same code base is running in a QA system with no errors.  Both servers are on the same build, Cedar-14, with the only difference being that the Prod server has a worker Dyno and QA does not.

```
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  Don't know how to build 
task 'jobs:work' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/bin/bundle:3:in `load' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  /app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>' 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  (See full trace by running task with --trace) 
Feb 01 11:24:46 skincaremarketplace heroku/worker.1:  Process exited with status 1 
Feb 01 11:40:45 skincaremarketplace heroku/worker.1:  State changed from crashed to starting 
Feb 01 11:40:52 skincaremarketplace heroku/worker.1:  Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work` 
Feb 01 11:40:52 skincaremarketplace heroku/worker.1:  State changed from starting to up 
Feb 01 11:41:02 skincaremarketplace heroku/worker.1:  Process exited with status 1 
Feb 01 11:41:02 skincaremarketplace heroku/worker.1:  State changed from up to crashed 
Feb 01 11:41:02 skincaremarketplace app/worker.1:  rake aborted!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the configuration on Heroku,  All of our other applications that follow the same pattern, do not use jobs:work, or have a jobs.rake file.  The worker was turned on in error.  The investigation did shed some light, so thank you Stan.

Answer (score 0):

Your prod server worker dyno tries to run `bundle exec rake jobs:work` (check your `Procfile`). Looks like you don't have that task. It normally should be in `lib/tasks/jobs.rake`.

If you scale up your QA workers they'll be failing too.

Comment: I am new to the platform and took this as a clone from another application that is not having these issues.  I am not sure what changed, but the other system is not having these issues. and the file set does not include Jobs:work or jobs.rake.

Comment: `heroku ps:scale worker=0 -a <name-of-your-prod-server>` will scale workers to 0 on prod. Then delete line `worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work` from your Procfile.